# Set character at the cursor location Editext

Tags: android-edittext, settext

My layout has an editext field and some button to set text to it. I do not know why some buttons can set text at the current cursor position and others don't.

In details, number "0, 1, 2" can be inserted in to current cursor position but the plus char "+".

My main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/displayLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="45"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#ffff"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:inputType="number" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

To set text on the current cursor position I used:

```
int start =editText.getSelectionStart(); //get the the cursor position
String s = "Some string";
editText.getText().insert(start, s); //get the text and insert the String
```

And the Onclick method

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    EditText result = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.result);

    int start = result.getSelectionStart(); 

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.digit0:
            result.getText().insert(start, "0");
            break;
        case R.id.digit1:
            result.getText().insert(start, "1");
            break;

        case R.id.digit2:
            result.getText().insert(start, "2");
            break;

        case R.id.plus:
            result.getText().insert(start, "+");
            break;
     }

}
```

I hope some one help me to figure out the problem. Thank you and I'm really appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is not a valid character if you set your `EditText` to `android:inputType="number"`. Are you trying to enter a phone number? You could try `android:inputType="phone"`